# Trouble integrating AWS Step Functions with API Gateway in CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Currently I'm trying to write a stack in CDK that creates an API Gateway and has one of the methods call an AWS Step Function to execute.

The code builds with `npm run build`, but during cdk deploy I get the error:

"AWS ARN for integration contains invalid action" and errors on the line that creates the root of the API.

```
// API Gateway Resources
    const dapi = new api.RestApi(this, 'Test-Gateway');

    const testID = dapi.root.addResource('{testID}');
    
    const getQuote = testID.addResource('GetQuote');
    
    getQuote.addMethod('POST', new api.AwsIntegration({
        service: 'states',
        action:  'Start Execution',
        proxy: false,
        integrationHttpMethod: 'POST',
        options: {
            passthroughBehavior: api.PassthroughBehavior.NEVER,
            credentialsRole: iam.Role.fromRoleArn(this, 'rolename', 'arnForExecutionRole'),
            requestTemplates: {
                'application/json': `{ 
                    "input": "{
                        \"Alias\": \"$input.params('Alias')\"
                    },
                    "stateMachineArn": "stateMachineArn"
                }`,
            },
            integrationResponses: [{
                statusCode: '200',
            }]
        }
    }), {
        methodResponses: [{ 
            statusCode: '200',
        }]
    }
    );
```

Im not sure *why* this doesn't work, as this is the same structure of a functioning one I built in the console. I feel I am either missing a parameter or has some parameter with an incorrect value. I haven't found any example of this so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use action name without spaces, i.e. `action:  'StartExecution'`